# Android ListView items animation - Animate only first visible items

Tags: android, listview, animation, offset

I'm trying to reproduce this ListView items:

http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/components-progressandactivity-progressandactivity-2-drive.mobile-load.folders_large_xhdpi.webm

I've successfuly achieved it with these lines of code (not counting animation xml file):

```
//Set animation
    if(position > lastAnimPosition){
        lastAnimPosition = position;

        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.item_slide_in);
        anim.setStartOffset(50 * position);
        row.startAnimation(anim);
    }
```

So animations are fine, but when I scroll down, there's problem with offset - it's just huge and it gives feel like the app is loading item for too long. **What I need to do, is find out when I should disable offset - or how to enable offset only for first showed items.**

Comment: Can you please post item_slide_in.

Comment: Could u plz post ur Item_slide_in animation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the layout animation attribute in your xml

Docs here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:layoutAnimation

add a file to your res/anim folder of `layout_item_slide_in.xml` that has a reference to `@anim/item_slide_in`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:delay="0.5"
        android:animation="@anim/item_slide_in" />
```

Now, change your listview xml slightty to include the android:layoutAnimation attribute and value

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/foo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_item_slide_in"" />
```

this will achieve the same first load animation style you want w/o having to do it in code

Comment: It works like a charm. But I've got question - is there any way how to reanimate this animation on events such as notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: try calling [mListView.startLayoutAnimation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#startLayoutAnimation()) on your listview reference in code after the `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` call

Comment: Is this possible for RecyclerView too?

Answer (score 0):

call `YOUR_LIST_VIEW.scheduleLayoutAnimation();` before `YOUR_ADAPTER.notifyDataSetChanged();` to reAnimate your list after dataSetChange